# Tracing costum tkinter is lagging

Tags: python, tkinter, trace, lag, customtkinter

[image]I have some issues with custom tkinter’s performance due to the trace method. I have one trace method in a class App there traces all of my StringVars. But I also have a method there keeps track of which tab there is open (‘Forside’, ‘Lastarrangement’, ‘Pulttag’, ‘Sadeltag’) so the trace methods only trace the StringVars attached to the corresponding tab. See the images that I’ve attached to this question.

My issue is, if there are too many StringVars to one of the tabs, in my case the ‘Sadeltag’ tab, then the program is lagging heavily. Personally, I don’t think that the 9 StringVars the program needs to trace in the ‘Sadeltag’ tab is much, but apparently for my program it is. But again, I’m kind of a noob, and I’m only scratching the surface of the programming world.
So, my question is. Is this just too much for a custom tkinter application to handle, or do I’ve some major design flaws in code structure?

My goal with the application is to have a program that updates dynamically when the variables change their values.

```
def trace_string_vars(self, *args):
        for tab in self.current_state.keys():
            # Tracing Forside
            if tab == 'Forside' and self.current_state[tab]:
                pass
            # Tracing Lastarrangement
            elif tab == 'Lastarrangement' and self.current_state[tab]:
                # entry_C_t
                C_t = self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].get()
                if len(C_t) == 2 and C_t[0] == '0' and C_t[1] != '.' or len(C_t) > 0 and C_t[0] == '.':
                    self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].set('0')
                try:
                    C_t = float(C_t)
                    if C_t > 1:
                        self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].set('1.0')
                except ValueError:
                    self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].set('')

                # label_C_top
                topografi = self.string_vars['combobox_C_top'].get()
                C_top = 1.00
                if topografi == 'Afskærmet':
                    C_top = 1.25
                elif topografi == 'Normal':
                    C_top = 1.00
                elif topografi == 'Vindblæst':
                    C_top = 0.80
                self.string_vars['label_C_top'].set(f'C_top\t=\t{C_top:.2f}')
                self.string_vars['label_C_top_screen'].set(f'\t\t{topografi}      \t\u21D2\tC_top = {C_top:.2f}')

                # entry l_1
                l_1 = self.string_vars['entry_l_1'].get()
                if len(l_1) == 2 and l_1[0] == '0' and l_1[1] != '.' or len(l_1) > 0 and l_1[0] == '.':
                    self.string_vars['entry_l_1'].set('')
                try:
                    l_1 = float(l_1)
                except ValueError:
                    self.string_vars['entry_l_1'].set('')

                # entry l_2
                l_2 = self.string_vars['entry_l_2'].get()
                if len(l_2) == 2 and l_2[0] == '0' and l_2[1] != '.' or len(l_2) > 0 and l_2[0] == '.':
                    self.string_vars['entry_l_2'].set('')
                try:
                    l_2 = float(l_2)
                except ValueError:
                    self.string_vars['entry_l_2'].set('')

                # entry h
                h = self.string_vars['entry_h'].get()
                if len(h) == 2 and h[0] == '0' and h[1] != '.' or len(h) > 0 and h[0] == '.':
                    self.string_vars['entry_h'].set('')
                try:
                    h = float(h)
                except ValueError:
                    self.string_vars['entry_h'].set('')

                # label C_s
                try:
                    C_s = 1.00
                    if topografi == 'Afskærmet':
                        C_s = 1.00
                        self.string_vars['label_C_s_screen'].set(f'\t\t{topografi}\t\u21D2\tC_s = 1.00')
                    elif 2 * h > l_1:
                        C_s = 1.00
                        self.string_vars['label_C_s_screen'].set('\t\t2 \u2022 h > l_1\t\t\u21D2\tC_s = 1.00')
                    else:
                        if l_2 <= 10 * h:
                            C_s = 1.00
                            self.string_vars['label_C_s_screen'].set('\t\t2 \u2022 h \u2264 l_1\t\tog\tl_2 \u2264 10 \u2022 h\t\u21D2\tC_s = 1.00')
                        elif l_2 >= 20 * h:
                            C_s = 1.25
                            self.string_vars['label_C_s_screen'].set('\t\t2 \u2022 h \u2264 l_1\t\tog\tl_2 \u2265 20 \u2022 h\t\u21D2\tC_s = 1.25')
                        else:
                            C_s = 1 + 0.025 * ((l_2 - 10 * h) / h)
                            self.string_vars['label_C_s_screen'].set(f'\t\t2 \u2022 h \u2264 l_1\t\tog\t10 \u2022 h < l_2 < 20 \u2022 h\t\t\u21D2\tC_s = 1 + 0.025 \u2022 ((l_2 - 10 \u2022 h) / h) = {C_s:.2f}')
                    self.string_vars['label_C_s'].set(f'C_s\t=\t{C_s:.2f}')
                except TypeError:
                    pass

                # label C_e
                C_e = C_top * C_s
                self.string_vars['label_C_e'].set(f'C_e\t=\t{C_e:.2f}')

            # Tracing Formfaktor
            elif tab == 'Tagudformning' and self.current_state['Forside'] == False:
                if tab == 'Tagudformning' and self.current_state['Lastarrangement'] == False:
                    for tagtype in self.current_state[tab].keys():
                        # Tracing Pulttag
                        if tagtype == 'Pulttag' and self.current_state[tab][tagtype]:
                            # Tagtype
                            self.tagudformning = self.string_vars['combobox_tagtype'].get()
                            if self.tagudformning in settings.TAGUDFORMNING_LIST:
                                self.formfaktor_button_click()
                            
                            # Brystværn
                            brystværn = self.pulttag_menu_frame.switch_bryst_pult.get()
                            if brystværn == 1:
                                self.string_vars['switch_bryst_pult'].set('Ja')
                            elif brystværn == 0:
                                self.string_vars['switch_bryst_pult'].set('Nej')

                            # entry_a_pult
                            a_pult = self.string_vars['entry_a_pult'].get()
                            if len(a_pult) == 2 and a_pult[0] == '0' and a_pult[1] != '.' or len(a_pult) > 0 and a_pult[0] == '.':
                                self.string_vars['entry_a_pult'].set('0')
                            try:
                                a_pult = float(a_pult)
                                if a_pult > 90:
                                    self.string_vars['entry_a_pult'].set('90.0')
                            except ValueError:
                                self.string_vars['entry_a_pult'].set('')

                            # label_u_pult
                            try:
                                if a_pult <= 30 or brystværn == 1:
                                    u_pult = 0.80
                                elif a_pult >= 60:
                                    u_pult = 0.00
                                else:
                                    u_pult = 0.8 * (60 - a_pult) / 30
                                self.string_vars['label_u_pult'].set(f'\u03BC_1\t=\t{u_pult:.2f}')
                            except TypeError:
                                pass
                            
                            # label_s_pult
                            try:
                                C_t = self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].get()
                                C_t = float(C_t)
                                C_e = self.string_vars['label_C_e'].get()[-4:]
                                C_e = float(C_e)
                                u_pult = self.string_vars['label_u_pult'].get()[-4:]
                                u_pult = float(u_pult)
                                s_pult = u_pult * C_e * C_t * 1
                                self.string_vars['label_s_pult'].set(f's\t=\t{s_pult:.2f} kN/m\u00B2')
                            except TypeError:
                                pass
                            
                            # canvas_pult01
                            self.update_canvas_pult01()
                            self.update_canvas_pult02()
                            
                        # Tracing Sadeltag
                        elif tagtype == 'Sadeltag' and self.current_state[tab][tagtype]:
                            # Tagtype
                            self.tagudformning = self.string_vars['combobox_tagtype'].get()
                            if self.tagudformning in settings.TAGUDFORMNING_LIST:
                                self.formfaktor_button_click()

                            # Brystværn
                            brystværn_v = self.sadeltag_menu_frame.switch_bryst_sadel_v.get()
                            if brystværn_v == 1:
                                self.string_vars['switch_bryst_sadel_v'].set('Ja')
                            elif brystværn_v == 0:
                                self.string_vars['switch_bryst_sadel_v'].set('Nej')

                            brystværn_h = self.sadeltag_menu_frame.switch_bryst_sadel_h.get()
                            if brystværn_h == 1:
                                self.string_vars['switch_bryst_sadel_h'].set('Ja')
                            elif brystværn_h == 0:
                                self.string_vars['switch_bryst_sadel_h'].set('Nej')

                            # entry_a_pult
                            a_sadel_v = self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_v'].get()
                            if len(a_sadel_v) == 2 and a_sadel_v[0] == '0' and a_sadel_v[1] != '.' or len(a_sadel_v) > 0 and a_sadel_v[0] == '.':
                                self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_v'].set('0')
                            try:
                                a_sadel_v = float(a_sadel_v)
                                if a_sadel_v > 90:
                                    self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_v'].set('90.0')
                            except ValueError:
                                self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_v'].set('')

                            a_sadel_h = self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_h'].get()
                            if len(a_sadel_h) == 2 and a_sadel_h[0] == '0' and a_sadel_h[1] != '.' or len(a_sadel_h) > 0 and a_sadel_h[0] == '.':
                                self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_h'].set('0')
                            try:
                                a_sadel_h = float(a_sadel_h)
                                if a_sadel_h > 90:
                                    self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_h'].set('90.0')
                            except ValueError:
                                self.string_vars['entry_a_sadel_h'].set('')

                            # label_u_pult
                            try:
                                if a_sadel_v <= 30 or brystværn_v == 1:
                                    u_sadel_v = 0.80
                                elif a_sadel_v >= 60:
                                    u_sadel_v = 0.00
                                else:
                                    u_sadel_v = 0.8 * (60 - a_sadel_v) / 30
                                self.string_vars['label_u_sadel_v'].set(f'\u03BC_1\t=\t{u_sadel_v:.2f}')
                            except TypeError:
                                pass

                            try:
                                if a_sadel_h <= 30 or brystværn_h == 1:
                                    u_sadel_h = 0.80
                                elif a_sadel_h >= 60:
                                    u_sadel_h = 0.00
                                else:
                                    u_sadel_h = 0.8 * (60 - a_sadel_h) / 30
                                self.string_vars['label_u_sadel_h'].set(f'\u03BC_2\t=\t{u_sadel_h:.2f}')
                            except TypeError:
                                pass

                            # label_s_pult
                            try:
                                C_t = self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].get()
                                C_t = float(C_t)
                                C_e = self.string_vars['label_C_e'].get()[-4:]
                                C_e = float(C_e)
                                u_sadel_v = self.string_vars['label_u_sadel_v'].get()[-4:]
                                u_sadel_v = float(u_sadel_v)
                                s_sadel_v = u_sadel_v * C_e * C_t * 1
                                self.string_vars['label_s_sadel_v'].set(f's_1\t=\t{s_sadel_v:.2f} kN/m\u00B2')
                            except TypeError:
                                pass

                            try:
                                C_t = self.string_vars['entry_C_t'].get()
                                C_t = float(C_t)
                                C_e = self.string_vars['label_C_e'].get()[-4:]
                                C_e = float(C_e)
                                u_sadel_h = self.string_vars['label_u_sadel_h'].get()[-4:]
                                u_sadel_h = float(u_sadel_h)
                                s_sadel_h = u_sadel_h * C_e * C_t * 1
                                self.string_vars['label_s_sadel_h'].set(f's_2\t=\t{s_sadel_h:.2f} kN/m\u00B2')
                            except TypeError:
                                pass
```

[image]

I’ve only attached my method for the tracing of the StringVars, because I believe that’s within there my problem occurs.

I only have issues with the 'Sadeltag' tab, the other tabs runs perfectly fine.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand when trace_string_vars is called: is it called in a loop to check if a var changed or is it called when a var changed (using the `variable.trace()` method).

If you use a loop to check if a variable changed, that is not the way to go: it is very slow and you should use the `variable.trace()` method.

If the function is called when a variable changed, you should probably make one function for each variable to trace so it does not run useless code each time a variable changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @fastattack! 
It’s called when a variable changes with the trace method. So yes all the variables runs the same method “string_var.trace(‘w’, self.trace_string_vars)”.
Yes, you’re probably right, I need a function for each variable. I just thought it was enough to reduce the number of variables the trace_string_vars method went through by limiting the tracing with keeping track of which tab is currently open, but I guess I was wrong. 
But again thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I know what I was doing wrong now. I had entry widgets which were connected to label widgets. And I traced them both with the trace method. So instead of the method to run only once then it will run twice instead. And with many entry widgets and label widgets set up this way it of course becomes very inefficient. So, I updated the label widgets with the configure method instead, and now it performs a lot better.

Comment: Please start by taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and [answer] and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**, and both questions and answers should not contain any "meta" content (i.e. talking about yourself or your experience with the site). When asking a question, it is your responsibility to attempt debugging first and use the results of your debugging to produce a [mre]. It should not take dozens of lines of code and multiple screenshots to understand the problem.

Comment: The issue people are probably having with your question is that it has a lot, a _lot_ of code with Danish variable names that's unlikely to help, and as the commenter noted, you didn't show how you were using the big function. Reducing your problem to an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) makes for a better question, and while building the MRE, you might also spot your performance issue before needing to even ask.

Comment: As for a comment on your code structure: there _is_ a lot of repetition and you're likely hiding actual bugs with too-broad `try: except:`s. I would consider restructuring things so the actual computation would be done by an entirely "headless" class that's separated from UI concerns.

Comment: And one more comment: in a Python program, if you find a code line being indented by 32 spaces, you're probably overdue to refactor that code into smaller, separate functions. 

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Karl Knechtel and AKX I appreciate your honesty. I will take the tour and reread your comments before asking my next question.